Issues changing page icon in .Net using Blazor
So recently I tried to change the file icon on my blazor project I am working, but I have run into some major issues with it. I simply just can't get it to load on my project.
Here is everything I have tried to do:
Replaced old favicon.ico with new favicon.ico
I changed my index.html to have  in the head. Also tried to do it in the shared MainLayout.razor files. I have tried changing the icon in both my Client and Server properties and I have cleared my cache.
I know the url link is valid as I can access it from my localhost by doing localhost:port/favicon.ico and it displays what I need it to, but I am really unsure why it isn't updating to the correct logo.

Provide more details and screenshots/code samples to convey your message.

Well that's an old one. I believe you're using a chrome based browser. Unfortunately your browser caches your favicon with no expiration (and no way to clear it). Go ahead and load your page in another browser and you'll see it's working just fine. I would ignore the problem (and actually I am ignoring it in my recent project for over three months) But you can always delete the favicons the hard way:
%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Favicons
(That's a sqlite database and you can also delete the records instead of deleting the file)

Thanks greatly appreciated! I really had no idea this was a thing and messed around with it for way too long.

@Krispify You're welcome. Been there myself. If your question is answered properly, please accept my answer by clicking the green tick in the side.
